# how to delete all log records belong to "GKE Container" service on Google Cloud

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I try to delete the huge log record belongs to `GKE Container` service. But I can not do that.

Here is

[image: See may huge log record on the screenshot]

Which one I should delete via "cloud beta logging logs` commands ?

Is there a way of delete all of log entities belongs to `GKE Container` service ?

All logs records are listed in follow the result of my shell.

```
$ gcloud beta logging logs list
NAME
projects/bonair-pass/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
projects/bonair-pass/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access
projects/bonair-pass/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Factivity_log
projects/bonair-pass/logs/docker
projects/bonair-pass/logs/event-exporter
projects/bonair-pass/logs/events
projects/bonair-pass/logs/feeder-for-old-tracker
projects/bonair-pass/logs/fluentd-gcp
projects/bonair-pass/logs/heapster
projects/bonair-pass/logs/kubelet
projects/bonair-pass/logs/mqtt-broker-service
projects/bonair-pass/logs/node-problem-detector
projects/bonair-pass/logs/prom-to-sd
projects/bonair-pass/logs/prometheus-to-sd-exporter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't beleive this is possible with a single command.

Logs are not stored in a hierarchical folder structure as demonstrated by the `gcloud beta logging logs list` command output.

If you are sure you would like to delete the logs defined under the 'GKE Container' category, you could delete the logs for each container separately by issuing the following command:

```
gcloud logging logs delete LOG_NAME
```

If you are unsure which logs in the list fall under the category 'GKE Container', you can check in the Stackdriver logging view, by navigating to:

```
GKE Container > Cluster name > namespace_id
```

This will populate the second drop-down menu with the name of the containers in that name space, which will correspond with the logs defined under GKE Container.

EDIT:

Even if you delete the logs, the value for Resource Usage will not go down, as the value represents the amount of logs generated within the month (not the amount of logs stored).

If you would like to stop receiving logs for GKE Container resources, you could apply an [exclusion filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions). This would allow you to control the logs you receive and do not receive, and control your costs.

In terms of your comment about deleting Audit Logs, these cannot be deleted. Admin Activity Audit Logs (and Bigquery data access audit logs) are exempt from exclusions and are not included in the totals for data used in your project.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have deleted all logs entities of listed in `gcloud logging logs list` result.  But I can  still see  `GKE Container 248.49 GB 182.9 GB` logs is exist on Log Resource page :|

Comment: By the way I can not delete `cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity` log entity. When  the entity was deleting, `gcloud` command returned an error message. The message is `ERROR: (gcloud.logging.logs.delete) PERMISSION_DENIED: Audit logs cannot be deleted.` Is it possible auidit log has very huge file space in the project ?

Comment: I've addressed this information now by editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use:

`gcloud beta logging logs list | grep "name" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -P 5 gcloud logging logs delete --quiet`

To delete all logs with "name".